# Difference between 延ばす and 伸ばす

Tags: words, nuances, word-choice

As far as I can tell, they both mean something like stretch or extend. When would you use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting のばす into Kanji and your IME should have a pop up that tells you the difference.

Mine (Google IME) says:

> **伸ばす**
>   1.長くする。「爪を伸ばす」「路線を伸ばす」
>   2.まっすぐにする。「背筋を伸ばす」「しわを伸ばす」
>   3.勢いなどを増やす。「勢力を増やす」
>
> **延ばす**
>   1.時間を遅らせる。延期する。「締め切りを延ばす」「出発を延ばす」
>   2.〈「伸ばす」とも〉既存のものに付け加えて長くする。「路線を延ばす」

So...

> **伸ばす** for
>   1. Making something longer. Ex. growing your nails, extending a route.
>   2. Making something straight. Ex. straightening your back or smoothing a wrinkle.
>   3. Increasing things like power/momentum. Ex. extending one's influence or power.
>
> **延ばす** for
>   1. Making the time of something later. Postponing something. Ex. extending a deadline or departure time.
>   2. Adding to something already existing such as a route to make it longer (`伸ばす` also OK for this).

Comment: Maybe think of it in terms of 延長 and 伸長.. wait that might not be helpful either

Answer (score 0):

延ばす is mainly used for extending "time or duration"

伸ばす is mainly used for extending "something tangible"